# Adobe Illustrator scripting

Tags: vbscript, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to create a scrips which will add different patterns saved as swatches, to a set of grouped items, which are part of a Layer. Unfortunately I can't find the right methods when looking through the Illustrator scripting guide. The grouped items have got a color property, which allows me to modify the base color, but I can't find any property which will allow changing the patterns.

Could anyone please assist?

Thank you,
Razvan Sodoleanu

Comment: What about [Adobe Illustrator CC 2017 Reference: VB Script (PDF, 2.0M) - Page 149](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/illustrator/pdf/Illustrator_VBScript_Reference_2017.pdf)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm trying to set the pattern to a grouped object. The pattern is defined in the Swatches list, and I'm trying to apply it to a grouped item. That's where I'm failing. This method, if I understand it correctly, does only allow me to change the color of a pattern.

Comment: @VasilyHall That's not it at all, the question needs some work before it can be re-opened. The problem is there is not enough information to understand what the OPs requirement is hence why is been closed as "Unclear". Elitism has absolutely nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that there's not a way to add a pattern from artwork using a script command - except there's a way with javascript to do an appExecuteMenuCommand to define the pattern. Well, we can run this little javascript from VBS without any problem, but the Pattern dialog comes up and we don't want that. So, simply send an Escape key to get out of the dialog, and your new pattern should be the latest swatch in the swatches collection!

```
Set AiApp = CreateObject("Illustrator.Application")
AppName = AiApp.Name
' MsgBox(AppName)
Set Doc = AiApp.ActiveDocument

Set MyGroup = Doc.GroupItems(1)
Doc.Selection = MyGroup

AiApp.DoJavaScript("app.executeMenuCommand('Adobe Make Pattern')")
Set WScriptShell =  CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScriptShell.SendKeys("{Escape}")
```

---

EDIT:
I read your question again and in fact I answered a different problem with the above. Your real answer is the following snippet. You can't apply patterns to groups, but you can apply them only to PathItems. If your PathItems are in a group, you can reach into the GroupItem to get its PathItems property. This example shows referencing a path on the document-level, which takes into account every single path in the document, nested or not. In my document I just have one rectangle to demonstrate the VBS code.

```
Set AiApp = CreateObject("Illustrator.Application")
Set Doc = AiApp.ActiveDocument

Set MyPatternSwatch = Doc.Swatches.GetByName("Alyssa")
Set MyRect = Doc.PathItems(1)

MyRect.FillColor = MyPatternSwatch.Color
```

Comment: If the question had been clearer maybe you would have answered the right problem. Your latest edit seems to be on the money though.

Comment: Maybe so, maybe not, I deal with folks all over the world some of whom come from places where English isn't the native language and communicating these intricate topics can be challenging even to the most accommodating questioners. Specifically, traversing both the artistic and software terminologies is difficult, and that's why I tend to advocate for leniency concerning this rather obscure domain of development. I hope I provided my viewpoint clearly.

Comment: That's fine but you have to understand [so] isn't here to answer every obscure question. If you think you can craft the question into something that reads better and explains the problem (it is a wiki after all), do it and i'll certainly vote to re-open.